# Setting pandas dataframe value based on row and column conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a fairly specific algorithm I want to follow.

Basically I have a dataframe as follows:

```
        month   taken   score
1       1       2       23
2       1       1       34
3       1       2       12
4       1       2       59
5       2       1       12
6       2       2       23
7       2       1       43
8       2       2       45
9       3       1       43
10      3       2       43
11      4       1       23
12      4       2       94
```

I want to make it so that the 'score' column is changed to 100 on days where taken == 2 continuously until the end of that month. So, not all occurrences of taken == 2 have their score set to 100, if any day following during that month has a taken == 1.

So the result I'd want is:

```
        month   taken   score
1       1       2       23
2       1       1       34
3       1       2       100
4       1       2       100
5       2       1       12
6       2       2       23
7       2       1       43
8       2       2       100
9       3       1       43
10      3       2       43
11      3       1       23
12      3       2       100
13      4       1       32
14      4       2       100
```

I've written this code which I feel should do it:

```
#iterate through months
for month in range(12):
    #iterate through scores
    for score in range(len(df_report.loc[df_report['month'] == month+1])):
        #starting from the bottom, of that month, if 'taken' == 2...
        if df_report.loc[df_report.month==month+1, 'taken'].iloc[-score-1] == 2:
            #then set the score to 100
            df_report.loc[df_report.month==month+1, 'score'].iloc[-score-2] = 100
        #if you run into a 'taken' == 1, move on to next month
        else: break
```

However, this doesn't appear to change any values, despite not throwing an error... it also doesn't give me an error about setting values to a copied dataframe.

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be that you're setting a copy of a copy with a new value. Chaining *loc calls isn't the best idea.

Comment: I think you're right, but how can I solve this? Also, if .loc isn't a copy, and .iloc isn't a copy, then why is an .iloc of a .loc a copy?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your values not being updated is that assignment to `iloc` updates the *copy* returned by the preceding `loc` call, so the original is not touched.

---

Here's how I'd tackle this. First, define a function `foo`.

```
def foo(df):
    for i in reversed(df.index):
        if df.loc[i, 'taken'] != 2:
            break
        df.loc[i, 'score'] = 100
        i -= 1
    return df
```

Now, `groupby` `month` and call `foo`:

```
df = df.groupby('month').apply(foo)
print(df) 
    month  taken  score
1       1      2     23
2       1      1     34
3       1      2    100
4       1      2    100
5       2      1     12
6       2      2     23
7       2      1     43
8       2      2    100
9       3      1     43
10      3      2    100
11      4      1     23
12      4      2    100
```

Obviously, `apply` has its shortcomings, but I cannot think of a vectorised approach to this problem.

Comment: Me neither. I can get rid of for loop but not the approach with apply in groupby

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
import numpy as np
def get_value(x):
    s = x['taken']
    # Get a mask of duplicate sequeence and change values using np.where
    mask = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)
    news = np.where(mask,100,x['score'])

    # if last number is 2 then change the news value to 100
    if s[s.idxmax()] == 2: news[-1] = 100 
    return pd.Series(news)

df['score'] = df.groupby('month').apply(get_value).values
```

Output :

```
   month  taken  score
1       1      2     23
2       1      1     34
3       1      2    100
4       1      2    100
5       2      1     12
6       2      2     23
7       2      1     43
8       2      2    100
9       3      1     43
10      3      2    100
11      4      1     23
12      4      2    100
```

Almost identical speed but @coldspeed is winner

```
ndf = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

%%timeit
ndf['score'] = ndf.groupby('month').apply(foo)
10 loops, best of 3: 40.8 ms per loop


%%timeit  
ndf['score'] = ndf.groupby('month').apply(get_value).values
10 loops, best of 3: 42.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Sure this is better than a simple iteration?

Comment: I dont know need to check the speed

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ its very very wierd. The difference is 2 milliseconds no matter how big the dataframe goes in my PC.

Comment: This isn't the kind of data for which it is very easy to time, because simply concatenating smaller `df`s to get a large df won't change things - you still have the same number of 2s at the end of each group. Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Yeah I too am curious abt the real data.